# PHP сдвиг вправо с заполнением нулями

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! В php есть сдвиг влево "<<" и вправо ">>". Как реализовать ">>>" сдвиг вправо с заполнением нулями в php, как в Java?

Comment: А чем php заполняет освобождающиеся биты при использовании ">>"?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов речь про знаковый бит, я так понимаю.

Comment: @teran у меня тоже про него подозрения...

Comment: к примеру в java или javascript операции сдвига ">>" и "<<" работают так же, как и в php ">>" и "<<". А вот ">>>" в php нету, как его реализовать, чтобы бы выполнял те же функции, что и ">>>" в javascript/java?

Comment: Печаль в PHP с целыми, я смотрю...

Comment: Я малость не в теме, но откопал, что `в PHP справедлива замена >>>  на abs($a >> $b)`

Comment: DaemonHD, спасибо)